# Is there a way to implement two way TCP communication using socket programming in c?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, ip

I have a two code files and I am trying to establish two way TCP communication. I have one way communication ready and working which is sending messages from client to the server and then the server printing it. I have been trying to establish a two way TCP connection, meaning that I can send messages from either machines.

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SERVER_PORT 5432
#define MAX_LINE 256

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    struct hostent *hp;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    char *host;
    char buf[MAX_LINE];
    int s;
    int len, new_s;

    if (argc==2) {
        host = argv[1];
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: simplex-talk host\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* translate host name into peer’s IP address */
    hp = gethostbyname(host);
    if (!hp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "simplex-talk: unknown host: %s\n", host);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* build address data structure */
    bzero((char *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy(hp->h_addr, (char *)&sin.sin_addr, hp->h_length);
    sin.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    /* active open */
    if ((s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("simplex-talk: socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin)) < 0) {
        perror("simplex-talk: connect");
        close(s);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* main loop: get and send lines of text */
    /*while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) {
        buf[MAX_LINE-1] = '\0';
        len = strlen(buf) + 1;
        send(s, buf, len, 0);
    }*/

    while(1){

        printf("sent: ");
        if(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)){
            buf[MAX_LINE-1] = '\0';
            len = strlen(buf)+1;
            send(s, buf, len, 0);
        }

        if((len = recv(new_s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)) != 0){
            printf("received: ");
            fputs(buf, stdout);

        }
    }
}
```

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SERVER_PORT 5432
#define MAX_PENDING 5
#define MAX_LINE 256

int main()
{
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    char buf[MAX_LINE];
    int len;
    int s, new_s;

    /* build address data structure */
    bzero((char *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sin.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    /* setup passive open */
    if ((s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("simplex-talk: socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin))) < 0) {
        perror("simplex-talk: bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    listen(s, MAX_PENDING);

    /* wait for connection, then receive and print text */
    while(1) {
        len = sizeof(sin);
        if ((new_s = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, (socklen_t *)&len)) < 0) {
            perror("simplex-talk: accept");
            exit(1);
        }



        while(1){

            if((len = recv(new_s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)) != 0){
                printf("received: ");
                fputs(buf, stdout);
            }


            printf("sent: ");
            if(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)){
                buf[MAX_LINE-1] = '\0';
                len = strlen(buf)+1;
                send(s, buf, len, 0);
            }

        }

        close(new_s);
    }
}
```

compilation:
`gcc -o server server.c`
`gcc -o client client.c`

Program execution:
Client side: `./client (ip address of the server machine)`
Server side: `./server`

---

Expected Result:
Client side:

```
sent: hi
received: hello world
sent: what is your name?
```

Server side:

```
received: hi
sent: hello world
received: what is your name?
```

---

Actual Result:
Client side:

```
sent: hi
received: hi
sent: ^C
```

Server side:

```
received: hi
sent: hello world
```

Comment: In server.c you have two while(1) loops which you never exit, as far as I can tell (i.e. there's no "break" keyword inside)

Comment: Sockets are inherently bidirectional — if you have a socket open between two processes,  each process can read from the socket file descriptor (and get data sent by the other end) and can write to the same socket file descriptor (and the data will be available at the other end).